# Call an interactive elisp-function inside an YaSnippet

Tags: yasnippet, interactive

When trying to evaluate an interactive elisp-function which needs an argument in a yasnippet, it gives the error wrong number of arguments. I assume, the reason is, that the function is interactive and thus needs an interactive argument which is not supplied, since it is inside the snippet.
This leads to the question:

How can I evaluate an interactive function inside a yasnippet?

.

Simple example snippet:

```
# name: xxx
# key: xxx
# type: command
# --
(cdlatex-math-modify)
```

When activating the snippet, I get the error message wrong number or arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use `call-interactively` to invoke an interactive command from Lisp code, drawing the required arguments from whatever sources are specified in the `(interactive)` declaration at the top of the command's function definition. It's as though you invoked the same command with `M-x` or a keybinding.

```
# name: math-modify
# key: mod
# type: command
# --
(call-interactively #'cdlatex-math-modify)
```

This even handles prefix arguments correctly. If you want to pass a prefix arg to `cdlatex-math-modify` when calling it this way, just type `C-u [arg]` immediately before invoking `yas/expand`. For instance, after you've entered the template key ("mod" here), type `C-u 2 TAB` to make `cdlatex-math-modify` operate on the last two words before point. It will percolate down.

Now, I don't know if this is the function you actually intend to create a snippet for, or if you just picked it as an example. But in this particular case, there's a problem with using a snippet triggered by a character sequence. Specifically, `cdlatex-math-modify` operates on the character before point, but [yasnippet only recognizes template key sequences when it sees them as whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847872/yasnippets-not-expanding-when-there-is-no-space-before-the-key) – that is, when they're preceded by a word separator or at the beginning of a buffer. As a result, this snippet only works to modify word-boundary characters, because that's the only kind of preceding character that can be there when it gets expanded. (You can do `C-u 1 TAB` as described above, but then it grabs the whole last word and the word boundary following it.) I'd just use a regular keybinding for this purpose.

Thanks for bringing `cdlatex-mode` to my attention; I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: FYI see this: https://github.com/tecosaur/LaTeX-auto-activating-snippets

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! Yes the plain cdlatex-math-modify was just an example, but one which is very close to my usecase.
I wrote a function which f.e. pushes the keystroke `>` to the cdlatex-math-modify-function, and thus, when i type `vec` my snippet does the same, that would happen, if i had pressed `' >`, and vec is much more convenient on my keyboard. With `(setq yas-key-syntaxes '(yas-longest-key-from-whitespace "w_.()" "w_." "w_" "w"))` in my init file the Yasnippet also gets expanded, when there is a character in front of it.

Comment: To Ian: This looks interesting, thanks! 
Right now, I am more or less happy with my set-up using YaSnippet, (which is a slightly modified version of, what this blogpost presented https://karthinks.com/software/latex-input-for-impatient-scholars/) but I have not found a solution for f.e. the subscripts. Maybe I'll try to use just the subscript part of this, if I can figure it out.